# Shopping Cart Price Rules change

Tags: magento

I want to amend shopping cart price rules and to add a new field there - subtotal with discount. Any idea how to do it? In addition to subtotal, i want to have subtotal with discount too, so that i can give discounts based on discounted subtotal, and not on base subtotal.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using fixed amount discount or % based discount?

Comment: it does not matter, I just want to be able to set the discount rule to consider discounted subtotal instead of normal one. All the rest is not relevant.

Comment: I wish this had been answered, I'm trying to go the exact same thing. :/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a related answer. It is not possible without custom modification.

> Without modification Magento does not allow this.
>
> Shopping Cart Price Rules are applied on the cart, whereas a grand
>   total is often not calculated until the last stage of the checkout.
>   Two very different touch points. This would be exceedingly difficult
>   to do, and I can't even begin to think where you would start.

[Related answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31742/magento-shopping-cart-rule-based-on-grand-total)